# Splitting column in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I split a column in pandas DataFrame by variable names in a column?
I have a DataFrame below:

```
    ID  FEATURE PARAM   VALUE
0   A101    U1  ITEM1   10
1   A101    U1  ITEM2   11
2   A101    U2  ITEM1   12
3   A101    U2  ITEM2   13
4   A102    U1  ITEM1   14
5   A102    U1  ITEM2   15
6   A102    U2  ITEM1   16
7   A102    U2  ITEM2   17
```

I want to split it as below.

```
    ID  FEATURE ITEM1   ITEM2
0   A101    U1  10  11
1   A101    U2  12  13
2   A102    U1  14  15
3   A102    U2  16  17
```

I tried to use one of the responses and it works great but partially.

```
Select_Data.groupby('PARAM')['VALUE'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T

PARAM   ITEM1   ITEM2
0   10  11
1   12  13
2   14  15
3   16  17
```

But I lost my ID & FEATURE columns and I want to keep them in the table. I will greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is my answer is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi Bharath, yes your answer worked for me. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `pivot_table` with index `ID,FEATURE` and then reset index i.e

```
ndf =  pd.pivot_table(df,columns='PARAM', values='VALUE',index=['ID','FEATURE']).reset_index()
```

Incase you want to aggregate duplicate values then you can use mean value

```
ndf =  pd.pivot_table(df,columns='PARAM', values='VALUE',index=['ID','FEATURE'],aggfunc='mean').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
PARAM    ID FEATURE  ITEM1  ITEM2
0      A101      U1     10     11
1      A101      U2     12     13
2      A102      U1     14     15
3      A102      U2     16     17
In [528]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` you can

```
In [566]: df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T
Out[566]:
c1  A  B  C
0   1  2  3
1   4  5  6
```

Comment: Awesome and simple

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['ID','FEATURE','PARAM'])['VALUE']
       .unstack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
     ID FEATURE  ITEM1  ITEM2
0  A101      U1     10     11
1  A101      U2     12     13
2  A102      U1     14     15
3  A102      U2     16     17
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

then use [Bharath shetty's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530301/2901002) or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean`, because duplicates in triples  `ID,FEATURE,PARAM`:

```
print (df)
     ID FEATURE  PARAM  VALUE
0  A101      U2  ITEM1     50<-same A101,U2,ITEM1
1  A101      U1  ITEM2     11
2  A101      U2  ITEM1     12<-same A101,U2,ITEM1
3  A101      U2  ITEM2     13
4  A102      U1  ITEM1     14
5  A102      U1  ITEM2     15
6  A102      U2  ITEM1     16
7  A102      U2  ITEM2     17


df = df.groupby(['ID','FEATURE','PARAM'])['VALUE'].mean()
       .unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
     ID FEATURE  ITEM1  ITEM2
0  A101      U1    NaN   11.0
1  A101      U2   31.0   13.0<-(50+12)/2=31
2  A102      U1   14.0   15.0
3  A102      U2   16.0   17.0
```